# ¿Cómo puedo acumular un valor en una variable con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Buenas noches.

¿Cómo puedo ir acumulando la suma de datos en una variable, con jQuery?
Tengo esto:

```
function ejemplo(){
  var obtenValor = $('.otraClase').attr("dato")
  var variableAcumuladora = 0

  $('.claseEjemplo').each(function(){
    variableAcumuladora += Number(datoAcumular)
  });

   capturaAcumulable = Number(variableAcumuladora)

   ...
}
```

Lo que pasa es que la `variableAcumuladora` me guarda el último valor ingresado y se suma así mismo el numero de veces que el `each` hace el recorrido. Por ejemplo si tengo con la variable `obtenValor`, y le paso los valores 10, luego 20 y luego 30, el resultado que me entrega es 90(lo cual no quiero); Lo que necesito es que la `variableAcumuladora` vaya obteniendo los valores que obtengo con `obtenValor`.

Por ejemplo:

Si `obtenValor` primero tiene un valor de 10, luego 20 y luego 30(dependiendo del recorrido del `each`), necesito que sume 10+20+30 = 60 y ese resultado lo guarde en la variable de `capturaAcumulable` para así poder imprimirlo en pantalla después.

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Saludos.

Añado el pedazo de html de donde obtengo el valor:

De hecho a lo que le estoy haciendo el each es a una tabla:

```
...
html +=  
       '<tr class="claseEjempo" dato="'+datoAcumular+'">'+
            '<td>'+valorEjemplo+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+valorEjemplo2+'</td>'+
            ...
         '</tr>'
```

Hay más código pero es donde yo obtengo el valor.

Answer (score 2):

Viendo tu código HTML, podrias intentar con esto:

```
  $('.claseEjemplo').each(function(){
    //Cambia esta linea
    //variableAcumuladora += Number(datoAcumular)
    // (El error es que la variable datoAcumular no existe, solo existe mientras creas la tabla, pero despues de eso solo es un valor de un atributo)
    //Por esta otra linea
    variableAcumuladora += Number($(this).attr("dato"));
    //$(this).attr("dato")<-- Con esta linea le dices que tome el valor del atributo dato de los objetos con la claseEjemplo (tr)
  });
```

Espero que las lineas anteriores te ayuden en tu caso especifico, saludos.

**Información anterior**

Necesitas iterar los renglones de la tabla, osea los `tr` y dentro de estos tomar la clase correspondiente para acumular el valor, al final mostralo en la clase que le corresponde pero a cada `tr` o `row`.  Revisa el ejemplo siguiente:

**Ejemplo con una tabla**

```js
function ejemplo() {
  
  $('tr').each(function() {
      var suma = 0;
     $(this).find(".sumar").each(function() {
         suma += Number($(this).attr("dato"));
      });
      $(this).find(".total").first().text(suma);
  });

}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/>
<input class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="ejemplo()" value="Calcular Acomulado" />
<br/>
<br/>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Valor 1</td>
      <td>Valor 2</td>
      <td>Valor 3</td>
      <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="sumar" dato="10">10</td>
      <td class="sumar" dato="20">20</td>
      <td class="sumar" dato="30">30</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sumar" dato="11">11</td>
      <td class="sumar" dato="21">21</td>
      <td class="sumar" dato="31">31</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sumar" dato="12">12</td>
      <td class="sumar" dato="22">22</td>
      <td class="sumar" dato="32">32</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="sumar" dato="13">13</td>
      <td class="sumar" dato="23">23</td>
      <td class="sumar" dato="33">33</td>
      <td class="total">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Información extra....**

En realidad no la estas acumulando porque tienes:

```
var variableAcumuladora = 0
```

dentro de la `función` y tendrias que declarar la variable `fuera de la función` para que no se reinicie el valor a cero cada vez que entres al método.

Checa este ejemplo, espero poder ayudarte :-)

```js
var variableAcumuladora = 0;

function ejemplo() {
  var valor = parseInt($("#valor").val());
  valor = isNaN(valor) ? 0 : valor;
  
  //La variableAcumuladora tendrias que declararla fuera de la función
  //de la forma como lo hacias la inicializabas cada vez
  variableAcumuladora += valor;
  
  $("#valor").val("");
  $("#valor").focus();
  $("#acumulado").text(variableAcumuladora);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Valor para acumular
<input type=number id="valor" />
<input type="button" value="Acumular" onclick="ejemplo()" />
<p>Valor acumulado
  <div id="acumulado"></div>
</p>
```

**Momento...**

Tendrías que mostrar tu código `HTML` porque puede que el `each` apunte siempre al mismo valor por eso solo te acumula lo ultimo, seria necesario verlo para saber que es lo hay en `each`, croe que allí esta el detalle no en el ciclo, me refiero a que desde un origen tienes 30 30 30  y no  10 20 30 como mencionas, a menos que estés llamando a otros objetos.

Si entendí un poco mejor lo que quieres hacer.... seria algo así:

```js
function ejemplo(){
  var variableAcumuladora =0;
   $('.otraClase').each(function(){
     var valor = $(this).attr("dato");
    variableAcumuladora += Number(valor) ;
  });
  
  $("#valor").text(variableAcumuladora);
  /*
  var obtenValor = $('.otraClase').attr("dato")
  var variableAcumuladora = 0

  $('.claseEjemplo').each(function(){
    variableAcumuladora += Number(datoAcumular)
  });

   capturaAcumulable = Number(variableAcumuladora)
*/
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="otraClase" dato="10">10</label>
<br/><label class="otraClase" dato="20">20</label>
<br/><label class="otraClase" dato="30">30</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type=button value="Acumular" onclick="ejemplo()"/>
<br/>
<p>Valor acumulado <div id="valor"></div></p>
```

Comment: De hecho a lo que le estoy haciendo el each es a una tabla:
...
html +=  
           '<tr class="claseEjempo" dato="'+datoAcumular+'">'+
                '<td>'+valorEjemplo+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+valorEjemplo2+'</td>'+
                ...
             '</tr>'
Hay más código, pero es donde yo obtengo el valor.

Comment: Ok, estas agarron por row... para sacar un todal por cada row... verdad???

Comment: Así es, es ua tabla y he ahí la cuestión...si se generan tres <tr> entonces me muestra el último valor tres veces.

Comment: Si es que no estas iterando bien tus `eachs`, necesitas irte por `tr`, primero recorrer los renglones y por cada renglón agarrar la clase que quieres sumar, checa el ejemplo y voy actualizar mi respuesta para ponerte el ejemplo de la tabla al inicio.  Saludos

Comment: Necesito el atributo que jalo en los tr, que en éste caso es "dato"

Comment: El dato lo tomas del `tr` o del `td`? si es del `tr`, después de iterar por `tr` como el ejemplo que te pongo, con `$(this).attr("dato")` lo puedes obtener, dentro de la función `$('tr').each`  usa `$(this)` y accedes a los datos del `tr`

Comment: De hecho tengo un botón, con un atributo "dato" el cual le envía a la tabla de "claseEjemplo" ese dato y cada "tr" contiene un valor que le proporciona el botón con el atributo "dato", en pocas palabras el valor no está visible, sino solamente como atributo almacenado.

Comment: Si analizas el ejemplo que te puse podrás ver que el VALOR lo tomo del atributo dato del td, si pudieras usar la lógica parecida a esa, podrías resolver tu problema especifico... no tienes que ser un genio para llegar a la solución...  Si necesitas ayuda mas especifica porque no encuentras como aplicar el ejemplo en tu caso, creo que seria de mucha ayuda que pusieras tu código HTML FINAL no el del PHP, sino el que ya se genera en el browser y explicars mas a detalle exactamente que es lo que quieres hacer, puedes poner alguna imagen tmb.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ocupar sessionStorage o localStorage, por el lado del cliente. Es una variable que se aloja como archivo temporal, donde puedes guardar informacion de hasta 5mb. Como puedes utilizarlo, a continuacion te muestro.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("variable", variablePasar);
```

Para rescatar el dato:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("variable");
```

Para eliminar el objeto:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("variable");
```

Tu caso en particular seria el siguiente:

```
function ejemplo(){
  var obtenValor = $('.otraClase').attr("dato");
  var variableAcumuladora = sessionStorage.getItem("variableAcumuladora");
  $('.claseEjemplo').each(function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("variableAcumuladora", variableAcumuladora + Number(datoAcumular));
  });

   variableAcumuladora = sessionStorage.getItem("variableAcumuladora");
   capturaAcumulable = Number(variableAcumuladora)

   ...
}
```

El beneficio de esto, es que lo podras llamar desde otra funcion. Si variableAcumuladora no esta definido, sera vacio, por lo cual si sumas cualquier numero con este vacio, este sera automaticamente el numero. Vale decir

*Null* + 5 = 5

Espero que sea de aporta y exito en tu trabajo :D